# WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. Windows 10

Tags: python, pip, path

When I try to install any package in a virtual environment in Python I got a message:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

I've checked a few solutions on stackoverflow but none of them seems to solve my problem, because  most of the solutions on stack tell to add path to Anaconda Python installation, but I don't use Anaconda or Conda or Miniconda).

I use Windows 10 and I have set environmental paths to my Python installations:

```
C:\Python38
C:\Python38\Scripts
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Scripts
```

In only one question on stack I've stumbled upon a comment that someone uses QGIS and adding paths to the QGIS Python installation didn't help anyway to solve this warning.

How to make installing pip packages work in a Python virtual environment?

Comment: I've edited my question. Shortly, solutions on stackoverflow suggests to add paths to the Anaconda Python installation but I don't use Anaconda. I have paths to my local Python installations and still get this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't get any replies I've decided to uninstall Python and get a newer one.

I've clicked Uninstall Python from the Windows Control Panel, but then I got an error that "No Python 3.8 installation was detected" despite I have Python 3.8 on my machine. And another 0x80070643 error. So I've clicked Change -> Repair and... it worked. Reparation has added Pythons paths again to my env. Now I am able to install packages in a virtual environment.

Thanks to the one who give -1 vote for my question. Good luck for everyone who uses Anaconda Python, because there are plenty of answers how to solve this problem for Anaconda users.

It turned out that solution to my problem was simple - Have you tried to uninstall and install Python again?

[image: error1 no installation][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDu3S.png)

[image: error2 0x80070643][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an2Rz.png)